# Автоматическое обновление запросов pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, pandas

Написал бота в телеграме - основная его задача показывать материалы с сайта, которые должен соскрабить (если так можно выражаться) pandas.

Запрос он отправляет только при включении бота, во время запроса он не обновляет эту информацию (т.е. бота нужно выключить и включить снова, чтобы он обновил данные).

Я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы скрабил pandas не вначале, а после каждого запроса от пользователя.

UPD: Хорошо, если код нужен, то скину. Заранее извиняюсь, если кого-то стошнит - я пока достаточно коряво пишу =( Сам код -

```
import telebot
import currency
import datetime

TOKEN = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time = str(now.year) + "." + str(now.month) + "." + str(now.day) + " " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ' + str(message.chat.username) + '! Какая валюта тебя интересует? На данный момент я знаю курс : \n1.Доллара\n2.Евро\n3.Фунта\n4.Франка\n5.Юан\n6.Иен')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler_text(message):
    if message.text == "Доллар" or "Dollar" or "USD" or "/usd" or "/dollar" or "1" or "/1":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Доллара на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.usd) + " Рублей")
    elif message.text == "Евро" or "Euro" or "/euro" or "2" or "/2":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Евро на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.eur) + " Рублей")
    elif message.text == "Фунт" or "lb" or "pound" or "/lb" or "/pound" or "3" or "/3":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Фунта на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.gbp) + " Рублей")
    elif message.text == "Иена" or "Yen" or "/yen" or "6" or "/6":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Иен на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.jpy) + " Рублей")
    elif message.text == "Юань" or "Yuan" or "/yuan" or "5" or "/5":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Юаней на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.cny) + " Рублей")
    elif message.text == "Франк" or "Frank" or "/frank" or "4" or "/4":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость Франков на на момент запроса (" + str(time)  + ") - " + str(currency.chf) + " Рублей")



bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Файл currency.py -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://www.finanz.ru/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni', encoding='utf-8')[1] \
       .dropna(axis=1)

usd1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^USD\/')]
eur1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^EUR\/')]
gbp1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^GBP\/')]
jpy1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^JPY\/')]
cny1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^CNY\/')]
chf1 = df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^CHF\/')]

usd = int(usd1[2][3]) / 10000
eur = int(eur1[2][2]) / 10000
gbp = int(gbp1[2][1]) / 10000
jpy = int(jpy1[2][4]) / 10000
cny = int(cny1[2][5]) / 10000
chf = int(chf1[2][6]) / 10000
```

Большое спасибо всем, кто проявляет интерес.

Comment: не понятно, кто или что не хочет обновляться? исправьте описание, объясните ситуацию подробнее

Comment: @Anatol Отредактировал, вроде бы стало яснее.

Comment: В чём именно проблема? Вы не знаете, как отследить момен, когда бот получает сообщение? Или не знаете, как вынести кусок кода в функцию и вызывать её в нужный момент? В любом случае, тег pandas тут не нужен, поскольку на логику вообще никак не будет влиять, что вы там в момент запроса вызываете - pandas, другой какой-то модуль или духов бездны.

Comment: без кода всё равно не разобраться в проблеме, дайте код

Comment: @Anatol Теперь, надеюсь, все в порядке)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы оформил это в виде функции ([как предложил @Anatol](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703886/211923)), которую можно вызывать в нужные моменты времени:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_curr_rates(curr_code='RUB'):
    # parse rates into Pandas.DataFrame
    # remove empty columns
    df = pd.read_html('http://www.finanz.ru/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni',
                      encoding='utf-8')[1] \
           .dropna(axis=1)
    # set real column names
    df.columns = ['curr_pair','bid','call','close','pct','abs_val','time']
    # filter DF: leaving only those currency pairs
    # where the second currency == `curr_code`
    # for example: ['USD/RUB','EUR/RUB','GBP/RUB', ...]
    df = df.loc[df['curr_pair'].str.contains(r'\/{}'.format(curr_code))]
    # parse first currency from the [curr_pair] into `curr` column
    df['curr'] = df['curr_pair'].str.split('/').str[0]
    # convert ['bid','call','close'] columns to numeric dtypes
    num_cols = ['bid','call','close']
    df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    # return a Pandas.Series with the currency as an index
    return df.set_index('curr')['bid']
```

Пример работы с функцией:

```
In [129]: rub = get_curr_rates()

In [130]: rub
Out[130]:
curr
GBP    781673
EUR    706812
USD    601056
JPY      5464
CNY     89988
CHF    623761
Name: bid, dtype: int64

In [131]: rub['USD']
Out[131]: 601056

In [132]: rub['USD'] / 10**4
Out[132]: 60.105600000000003

In [133]: rub['EUR'] / 10**4
Out[133]: 70.681200000000004

In [134]: uah = get_curr_rates(curr_code='UAH')

In [135]: uah
Out[135]:
curr
EUR    301896
USD    257125
CHF    266838
GBP    334468
Name: bid, dtype: int64

In [136]: uah['USD'] / 10**4
Out[136]: 25.712499999999999
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ! =)

Answer (score 0):

На питоне не пишу, но попробуйте вместо импорта файла со статичными (!) значениями переписать всё это в функцию с параметром "*валюта*" (или без параметров) и вызывать её по каждому событию в `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`.

По факту тут просто однократное вычисление идёт с записью значений в переменные и потом обращение к этим переменным. А надо, чтоб значения вычислялись каждый раз при обращении, т.е. функция нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Извиняюсь за долгие ответы - не было возможности зайти и написать.